# Using rvest, xml2 and selector gadget for webscraping results in xml_missing <NA>

Tags: r, web, web-scraping, rvest, xml2

I'm trying to scrape information from the following URL:

https://www.google.com/search?q=812-800%20H%20St%20NW

I want to retrieve the highlighted "812 H St NW": [target][1]

The selector gadget (chrome extension) suggests to use the following node ".desktop-title-content"

However, I get an NA as a result and I don't get how to fix this problem.

Here is my code:

```
link <- "https://www.google.com/search?q=812-800%20H%20St%20NW"
xml2::read_html(link) %>% 
  rvest::html_node(".desktop-title-content") %>%  rvest::html_text()

[1] NA
```

Thank you
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzY75.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the content that I want to get is generated by javascript. Therefore, I need to create a .js file and access it using phantom JS as per this tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-javascript-generated-data-with-r

Then, I will be able to use rvest to **scrape** the correct content.

Unfortunately, I need to do this for around 2000 different links. I will be looking for a solution to automatically create 2000 ".js" files.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check the source page when SelectorGadget does not help you well. In this case, you just need to find text between `<title>` and `</title>`. I had some extra text (i.e., - google search) in the text. So I removed it in the end. You may not have that.

```
read_html("https://www.google.com/search?q=812-800%20H%20St%20NW") %>% 
html_nodes("title") %>% 
html_text() %>%
sub(pattern = " -.*$", replacement = "")

#[1] "812-800 H St NW "
```